# Start Up Disk Creator

Tags: 12.10, upgrade, usb

When I try to make a bookable USB stick it will only work with the FAT format....but when I try to create it with the NTSB format it wont work....Internal HDD is in the NTSB format..Does this matter?

Answer (score 0):

The quick answer is: No, it does not matter.

The format of a startup disk and the format of your hard drive is two completely different things. Ubuntu itself cannot be installed on a FAT or a NTFS partition and the installer will help you select either unpartitioned space or reduce your NTFS partition to allow for a Ubuntu system to be installed alongside of whatever you have already installed.

You may access you files on any FAT or NTFS partitions from Ubuntu after installation given that you didn't choose to destroy it in the installation process.

PS: If you already have Ubuntu installed the recommended way of upgrading is with `update-manager`. Press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and enter `update-manager` or write `update-manager` in dash.